# Perl to find the extension of file

Tags: perl

I have a program that takes directory name as input from user and searches all files inside the directory and prints the contents of file.  Is there any way so that I can read the extension of file and read the contents of file that are of specified extension?  For example, it should read contents of file that is in ".txt" format.

My code is

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
#usr/bin/perl
print "enter  a directory name\n";
my $dir = <>;
print "you have entered $dir \n";
chomp($dir);
opendir DIR, $dir or die "cannot open directory $!";
while ( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) {
    next if ( $file =~ m/^\./ );
    my $filepath = "${dir}${file}";
    print "$filepath\n";
    print " $file \n";

    open( my $fh, '<', $filepath ) or die "unable to open the $file  $!";
    while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
        chomp $row;
        print "$row\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look for the standard core Perl module [File::Basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html)?

Comment: actually when i open the file ,it contains list of file names.i have to check wheather .txt file exists or not,that is my requirment

Comment: OK; and what facilities does File::Basename provide that would help you?  What is difficult to understand about the manual page?

Comment: can i use grep command to match file extesion?

Comment: if yes..then what would be the way to  use it?

Comment: I'd say "No".  It's probably not strictly accurate, but it is an abuse of Perl's `grep` to use it in this context.

Comment: I wouldn't trust the "extension" of a file name.  Just because a file's name ends in `.txt` does not mean its a text file.

Comment: ok fine. if i give have a txt file that contains list of file names.i want to check in that wheather some kind of file exists or not? how will i be able to do ot?

Comment: if($row eq /.txt/) is this is correct?

Answer (score 1):

To get just the ".txt" files, you can use a file test operator (-f : regular file) and a regex.

```
my @files = grep { -f && /\.txt$/ } readdir $dir;
```

Otherwise, you can look for just text files, using perl's -T (ascii-text file test operator)

```
my @files = grep { -T } readdir $dir;
```

Otherwise you can try even this:

```
my @files = grep {-f} glob("$dir/*.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close here. You have a main loop that looks like this:

```
while ( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) {
    next if $file =~ /^\./; # skip hidden files

    # do stuff
}
```

See where you're skipping loop iterations if the filename starts with a dot. That's an excellent place to put any other skip requirements that you have - like skipping files that don't end with '.txt'.

```
while ( my $file = readdir(DIR) ) {
    next if $file =~ /^\./; # skip hidden files
    next unless $file =~ /\.txt$/i; # skip non-text files

    # do stuff
}
```

In the same way as your original test checked for the start of the string (`^`) followed by a literal dot (`\.`), we're now searching for a dot (`\.`) followed by `txt` and the end of the string (`$`). Note that I've also added the `/i` option to the match operator to make the match case-insensitive - so that we match ".TXT" as well as ".txt".

It's worth noting that the extension of a file is a terrible way to work out what the file contains.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Below code gives what you expect.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
print "Enter the directory name: ";
chomp(my $dir=<>);
print "Enter the file extension type: "; #only type the file format. like txt  rtf  
chomp(my $ext=<>);
opendir('dir',"$dir");
my @files = grep{m/.$ext/g} readdir('dir');
foreach my $ech(@files){
    open('file',"$dir/$ech");
    print <file>;
}
```

I'm store the all file from the particular directory to store the one array and i get the particular file format by using the grep command. Then open the files into the `foreach` condition